# Create dictionary with two keys where both keys must be met to retrieve value

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have two dataframes:

df_one:

```
person  city   year   col_x
ah       bos   1998
bc       bos   1996
dm       ny    2001
hh       la    1999
```

df_two:

```
person   city  range_a  range_b
mk       bos   1995     2004
kk       bos   2004     2017
ab       ny    1977     2019
fc       dc    2001     2005
cc       dc    2006     2019
et       la    1995     2005
tr      mia    1997     2006
```

I'd like to fill df_one, col_x with values based on conditions in both df_one and df_two.  You would take the city from df_one, match the city from df_two, and based on the where the year on df_one falls in between the range from df_two - you would place the person on df_two into col_x on df_one.

Example: "ah" from the first row in df_one - the city is bos, and the year 1998 - so col_x would be mk for that row, because the city matches and 1998 falls between 1995 and 2004.

I'm not really sure where to start with this on pandas; I believe it may be some kind of nested dictionary with two values, but not sure if that's possible.

Comment: _I'm not really sure where to start with this on pandas_ Read the Pandas docs, then.

Comment: Going by the condition you mentioned  'la' from last row of df_one, 1999 can fall in two places in df_two - and hence can choose  'et' and 'tr'. Please clarify how do you want to choose between multiple values. Is it that you want to take the first value or last?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you're after more clearly. You mention in the title you want to retrieve a value only when both keys match, but then talk about finding a value where the key is between two other values?

Comment: @instinct246 I edited my OP to be more specific and also fixed a typo with the data - but yes, you are filling the data in the missing column with data from the "person" column

Comment: @BrettJeffreson to clarify - you would be filling in the cells on col_x with the value from the person column of df_two when the city matches and also the the year falls in between the range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go about it.
First I created the data frame based on your description:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ah','bc','dm','hh'], 'B':['bos','bos','ny','la'], 'C': [1998,1996,2001,1999]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['mk','kk','ab','fc','cc','et','tr'], 'B':['bos','bos','ny','dc','dc','la','la'],'C': [1995,2004,1977,2001,2006,1995,1997], 'D':[2004,2017,2019,2005,2019,2005,2006] })

df1

A   B   C
0   ah  bos 1998
1   bc  bos 1996
2   dm  ny  2001
3   hh  la  1999

df2
A   B   C   D
0   mk  bos 1995    2004
1   kk  bos 2004    2017
2   ab  ny  1977    2019
3   fc  dc  2001    2005
4   cc  dc  2006    2019
5   et  la  1995    2005
6   tr  la  1997    2006
```

Then passed the rows of df1 to a function(check data). The function compares each row of df1 with all the rows in df2 and returns all the matching values from df2['A'] based on the condition you have mentioned. **Please read my comment to your original question. 'la' in df1 will choose 2 values in df2.**
**Option1:** I have chosen all the values for df1['D'] and that comes as a list. 
**Option 2**: I have chosen only the first value out of all the matching values which is put as a singular value.

*You can choose which option you want to go for or clarify further.*

**Option 1:**

```
def check_data(row):
    return  (df2[ (df2['B'] == row['B']) & (df2['C'] <= row['C']) & (df2['D'] >= row['C'])]['A'].values)
df1['D'] = df1.apply(check_data, axis=1)

df1

A   B   C   D
0   ah  bos 1998    [mk]
1   bc  bos 1996    [mk]
2   dm  ny  2001    [ab]
3   hh  la  1999    [et, tr]
```

**Option 2:**

```
def check_data(row):
    return  (df2[ (df2['B'] == row['B']) & (df2['C'] <= row['C']) & (df2['D'] >= row['C'])]['A'].iloc[0])
df1['D'] = df1.apply(check_data, axis=1)

df1
A   B   C   D
0   ah  bos 1998    mk
1   bc  bos 1996    mk
2   dm  ny  2001    ab
3   hh  la  1999    et
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataframe merge, then use lambda expression to compute column as per your required logic.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
```

First dataframe:

```
df_one = pd.DataFrame([
        {'A': 'ah', 'B': 'bos', 'C': 1998, 'D': ''},
        {'A': 'bc', 'B': 'bos', 'C': 1996, 'D': ''},
        {'A': 'dm', 'B': 'ny', 'C': 2001, 'D': ''},
        {'A': 'hh', 'B': 'la', 'C': 1999, 'D': ''},
    ])
print("df_one")
print(df_one)
```

Second dataframe:

```
df_two = pd.DataFrame([
        {'A': 'mk', 'B': 'bos', 'C': 1995, 'D': 2004},
        {'A': 'kk', 'B': 'bos', 'C': 2004, 'D': 2017},
        {'A': 'ab', 'B': 'ny', 'C': 1977, 'D': 2019},
        {'A': 'fc', 'B': 'dc', 'C': 2001, 'D': 2005},
        {'A': 'cc', 'B': 'dc', 'C': 2006, 'D': 2019},
        {'A': 'et', 'B': 'la', 'C': 1995, 'D': 2005},
        {'A': 'tr', 'B': 'la', 'C': 1997, 'D': 2006},
    ])
print("df_two")
print(df_two)
```

Merge the dataframes on column B:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_one, df_two, on='B')
print("df_merged")
print(df_merged)
```

Perform your logic:

```
df_merged['D_x'] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: x['A_y'] if x['C_y'] <= x['C_x'] <= x['D_y'] else '', axis=1)
print(df_merged)
```

Get required columns only:

```
result_columns = ['A_x', 'B', 'C_x', 'D_x']
df_result = df_merged[result_columns]
```

Rename the columns to desired format:

```
df_result = df_result.rename(columns={'A_x': 'A', 'C_x': 'C', 'D_x': 'D'})
```

Clean up records with blank value of D:

```
df_result = df_result[df_result['D'] != '']
print("df_result")
print(df_result)
```